# Writing a file to a bare repostory not at the root with NodeGit / LibGit2

Tags: javascript, libgit2, nodegit

I've been able to write a file to a branch in a bare repository using the below code, but it only works for files in the root. I haven't been able to find a good example in the documentation of how to build a tree for a subfolder and use that as a commit.

```
async function writeFile(filename, buffer) {
  const signature = NodeGit.Signature.now('Jamie', 'jamie@diffblue.com');
  const repo = await NodeGit.Repository.openBare('java-demo.git');
  const commit = await repo.getBranchCommit('master');
  const rootTree = await commit.getTree();
  const builder = await NodeGit.Treebuilder.create(repo, rootTree);
  const oid = await NodeGit.Blob.createFromBuffer(repo, buffer, buffer.length);
  await builder.insert(filename, oid, NodeGit.TreeEntry.FILEMODE.BLOB);
  const finalOid = await builder.write();
  await repo.createCommit('refs/heads/master', signature, signature, 'Commit message', finalOid, [commit]);
}

const buffer = new Buffer('Hello\n', 'utf-8');
writeFile('test.txt', buffer).then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

What modifications would be needed to post in (for example) src/test.txt, instead of test.txt?

Comment: It seems that this issue is not very clear and no example exists in the nodegit repo. 
Did you find an answer or solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The typical workflow for writing trees goes through the index. For example, `git_index_add_frombuffer` followed by `git_index_write_tree`. Even if you don't want to write to the repository's index on disk, you can still use the index interface by creating an in-memory index.

In a bare repository without an index, you can use `git_index_new` followed by `git_index_read_tree` to get an index initialized to the contents of your tree. Then write the tree out to the repository with `git_index_write_tree_to`.

I'm less familiar with the treebuilder interface, but it looks like you would have to create new subtrees recursively. For example, get or create the `src` subtree and insert the `test.txt` blob into it. Then get or create the root tree and insert the `src` subtree into it.

Comment: Nodegit doesn't seem to have an equivalent to `git_index_add_frombuffer`, which means I'll have to try the creating subtrees recursively route for now...